# Why do hotstrings act unexpectedly?

Tags: autohotkey

I have to test cases:

## Case 1

```
#Include test1.ahk
::se::Stack Exchange `{backspace}
```

(test1.ahk is empty) then typing:

- `se␣` (with a space at the end) → `Stack Exchange` (no space at the end)
- `use␣` → `uStack Exchange`

But let say I delete the `␣{backspace}` at the end or change it to

```
::se::Stack Exchange `{backspace}
::de::define
```

then it works normally again.

## Case 2

```
#Include test1.ahk
::se::Stack Exchange
```

works fine, but

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class SunAwtFrame
return
::se::Stack Exchange
```

makes `se`→`se`, i.e. nothing happens.

This is very weird, because there's nothing seems to be wrong. I can't even quarantine it, and updating AHK to the latest version or reinstalling it doesn't help. All I know is that when it happens any hotstring will behave this way. The problem started when I included [this script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alexmick/emoji-to-ahk/master/emoji.ahk), but even when I've exclude it this still happens. The script itself doesn't seem anything wrong too.

<sup>Also ask on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/9gr8wh/why_do_hotstrings_act_unexpectedly/?st=jm75pcd5&sh=2591e918).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Preventing expansion of <kbd>se</kbd> to trigger when you type <kbd>use</kbd>, is one of the reasons why I end my text expansion strings with a special character. As I maintain text expansion for three languages, I have settled on the following scheme.

```
text\ is the default (Dutch)
text= is used for English
text] is used for German
```

I also use the <kbd>.</kbd> in some cases to expand abbreviations.
I chose the <kbd>\</kbd>, <kbd>=</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> signs, because they are all close to the Enter key.

Example:

Dutch:

```
:*:adhv\::aan de hand van
:*:bv\::bijvoorbeeld
```

English:

```
:*:am=::Account Management
:*:actm=::Active Monitoring
:*:appr=::approach
:*:art=::article
:*:ba=::business alignment
```

German:

```
:*:nrw]::Nordrhein-Westfalen
:*:ma]::Mitarbeiter
:*:fk]::Führungskräfte
```

Dots:

```
:*:adhv.::a.d.h.v.
:*:dmv.::d.m.v.
:*:ovv.::o.v.v.
```

As you can see, I can write <kbd>adhv</kbd> either with a <kbd>.</kbd> at the end or with a <kbd>\</kbd> and they expand differently.

The * is used to overwrite the default ending characters like {Space}.